# How to get the body of a byte message in JMS ActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I have a code that gets a message from a JMS queue, but I don't understand how to get the body of the message if it is a byte and translate it into a `String`:

```java
connectQueueBrowser();
Enumeration<Message> messageEnumeration =  queueBrowser.getEnumeration();
ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
while (messageEnumeration.hasMoreElements()){
   messages.add(messageEnumeration.nextElement());
}
System.out.println(messages.get(0).getBody(String.class));
```

This is the error I get:

```
javax.jms.MessageFormatException: Body not assignable to class java.lang.String
```

But I get an error when I display body messages.

Comment: Are you sending a text message to the queue? Something like `session.createTextMessage(stringMessage)`.

Comment: From the Javadoc for [`Message.getBody()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getBody-java.lang.Class-): "If the message is a `BytesMessage` then this parameter must be set to `byte[].class`". If it is a byte message you can cast it to `BytesMessage` and proceed from there. Why you are using a `String` for bytes is another mystery. `String` is not a container for binary data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have sent a JMS `BytesMessage` then you can **only** use `getBody` with `byte[].class`, e.g.:

```java
System.out.println(messages.get(0).getBody(byte[].class));
```

If you've serialized a Java `String` into the `BytesMessage` using something like this:

```java
bytesMessage.writeBytes(myString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Then you'll be able to deserialize that `String` from the `BytesMessage` using something like this:

```java
byte[] myBytes = new byte[(int)bytesMessage.getBodyLength()];
bytesMessage.readBytes(myBytes);      
String myString = new String(myBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```